# MySQL LIKE + php sprintf

Tags: php, mysql, printf, sql-like

```
$test = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `text` LIKE '%%s%'", mysql_real_escape_string('test'));

echo $test;
```

output:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `text` LIKE '%s
```

but it should output:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `text` LIKE '%test%'
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
... LIKE '%%%s%%'", mysql_real_escape_string('test'));
```

To print the `%` character you need to escape it with itself. Therefore the first two `%%` will print the `%` character, while the third one is for the type specifier `%s`. You need a double `%%` at the end as well.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$test = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `text` LIKE '%%%s%%'", mysql_real_escape_string('test'));
```

In `sprintf`, if you want to get a `%` sign, you have to insert `%%`. So it's `%%` for the first wildcard `%`, `%s` for the string itself and `%%` for the last wildcard `%`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the percent signs with a percent sign `%%`.

```
$test = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `text` LIKE '%%%s%%'", mysql_real_escape_string('test'));

echo $test;
```

Answer (score 1):

You’re jumbling contexts. For consistency, put the things that aren't inside the SQL single quotes outside of the **sprintf()** format string:

```
$test = sprintf(
          "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE"
            . "`xt` LIKE '%s'",
          "%" . mysql_real_escape_string("test") . "%"
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$test = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `text` LIKE '%s%'" . mysql_real_escape_string('test');

echo $test;
```