# PHP Filter a Recordset

Tags: php

Working on an online inventory system located here... http://wheelworldinc.com/catalog/viewsizesearch.php

There's 2 quantity columns... one for Portland, one for California.

I want to list results with highest quantity at top to lowest quantity at bottom for Portland only.  So the california quantity doesn't matter for display order.

Here's the code from the page...

```html
<?php require_once('../Connections/wheel.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . doubleval($theValue) . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$colname_Recordset1 = "-1";
if (isset($_POST['size'])) {
  $colname_Recordset1 = $_POST['size'];
}
$colname2_Recordset1 = "-1";
if (isset($_POST['inholes'])) {
  $colname2_Recordset1 = $_POST['inholes'] ."x" . $_POST['indiameter'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_wheel, $wheel);
 
$query_Recordset1 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `catalog` WHERE `size` LIKE %s AND `boltpattern` LIKE %s AND (`catalog`.Utah NOT LIKE 0 OR `catalog`.portland NOT LIKE 0 OR `catalog`.cal NOT LIKE 0) ORDER BY partnumber", GetSQLValueString("%" . $colname_Recordset1 . "%", "text"),GetSQLValueString("%" . $colname2_Recordset1 . "%", "text"));
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $wheel) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!-- DW6 -->
<head>
<!-- Copyright 2005 Macromedia, Inc. All rights reserved. -->
<title>Wheel World Database Admin Area</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="admin/mm_entertainment.css" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">

<!--
a {
 font-family: Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif;
 color: #99CCE6;
}
a:link {
 text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
 text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
 color: #000099;
}
a:active {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.style2 {font-size: large}
.style3 {font-size: x-large}
.style4 {font-size: 18px}
-->
</style></head>
<body bgcolor="#14285f">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr bgcolor="02021e">
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#000000"><img src="images/orange-banner.jpg" alt="Header image" width="720" height="156" border="0" /></td>
    <td height="58" colspan="2" valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#000000" id="logo">Online Inventory </td>
    <td width="68" bgcolor="#000000">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="02021E">
    <td height="57" colspan="2" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#000000" id="tagline"><br />   </td>
 <td width="68" bgcolor="#000000">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5" bgcolor="#cc3300"><img src="admin/mm_spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="2" border="0" /></td>
  </tr>

   <tr>
    <td colspan="5"><img src="admin/mm_spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="2" border="0" /></td>
  </tr>

   <tr>
    <td colspan="5" bgcolor="#cc3300"><img src="admin/mm_spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="5" id="dateformat">&nbsp;<br />
 &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="index.php">Search</a><br />
 &nbsp; &nbsp;<br /> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="192" align="left" valign="top"><div align="center" class="style3"></div>
    <td colspan="2" valign="top"><br />
 <table width="683" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td class="subHeader">Welcome to the Wheel World Inc Online Inventory</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="left" valign="top" class="bodyText">
            <form id="emptyquantity" name="emptyquantity" method="post" action="viewsizesearchempty.php">
              <label>
              <div align="center">
                <input type="hidden" name="size" value="<?php echo $_POST['size']; ?>" id="size" /><input name="inholes" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['inholes']; ?>" /><input name="indiameter" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['indiameter']; ?>" />
                Click here to view Part Numbers which may be available for special   order:
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="  View Zero Quantities  " />
              </div>
              </label>
                        </form>
            <p align="center" class="style4">&nbsp;</p>
            <?php if ($totalRows_Recordset1 == 0) { // Show if recordset empty ?>
              <p class="style3">No Results for this Size!</p>
              <?php } // Show if recordset empty ?>
<?php if ($totalRows_Recordset1 > 0) { // Show if recordset not empty ?>
                  <span class="style2">Results for Search for Wheel Size <?php echo $_POST['size']; ?> BoltPattern <?php echo $_POST['inholes']; ?>x<?php echo $_POST['indiameter']; ?></span> <br />
                  <br />
              <table width="725" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#0066FF">
        <tr>
          <td width="106" align="center">Photo</td>
          <td width="185" align="center">partnumber</td>
          <td width="172" align="center">Description</td>
          <td width="234" colspan="3" align="center" >Warehouses/Quantity</td>
        </tr>
        <?php do { ?>
          <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" align="center"><a href="viewitem.php?id=<?php echo ($row_Recordset1['id'].'&size='.$_POST['size'].'&bolt='.$_POST['inholes'].'&dia='.$_POST['indiameter']);?>"><img  border="0" width="100"src="admin/wheelthumb/tn_<?php echo $row_Recordset1['image']; ?>" vspace="3" /></a></td>
            <td rowspan="2" align="center"><a href="viewitem.php?id=<?php echo $row_Recordset1['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['partnumber']; ?></a></td>
            <td rowspan="2" align="center"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['description']; ?></td>
            
            <td align="center" valign="middle">Portland</td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle">California</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            
            <td align="center"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['portland']; ?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['cal']; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
            </table>
                  <?php } // Show if recordset not empty ?><br /></td>
  </tr>
      </table></td>
    <td width="125">&nbsp;</td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="192">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="564">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="325">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="125">&nbsp;</td>
 <td width="68">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($Recordset1);
?>
```

Any help would surely be appreciated!

Comment: Make use of MySQL's `MIN()` and `MAX()` aggregate functions and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I checked your site and you didn't mention the error you're getting *Unknown column 'quantity' in 'order clause'*. `%s` <= you need to wrap those in quotes. Consult this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3863217/ and http://stackoverflow.com/a/5827361/

Comment: what about this... $query_Recordset1 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `catalog` WHERE `size` LIKE %s AND `boltpattern` LIKE %s AND (`catalog`.Utah NOT LIKE 0 OR `catalog`.portland NOT LIKE 0 OR `catalog`.cal NOT LIKE 0) ORDER BY portland", GetSQLValueString("%" . $colname_Recordset1 . "%", "text"),GetSQLValueString("%" . $colname2_Recordset1 . "%", "text"));

Comment: it's showing it with highest quantity at bottom and lowest at top... is there a different call than "ORDER BY" that will order them ascending?

Comment: sorry, also you must go to this page first.. http://wheelworldinc.com/catalog/index.php     and put in a valid wheel configuration.. so put size 17 bolt pattern 4 x 100 to see results.  sorry guys.

Comment: Do a `group by` with the column you want, or change the `order by` to DESC instead of ASC or vice-versa.